# Transferring custom excel ribbons in local computer to other computers in Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, macros

I have created certain Macros. By customizing the ribbon ,i converted the Macros into buttons.
I saved the file as an `add-in (.xlam)`. Now, when i send the file to other people, I shall tell them to copy the file to XLstart folder

When they open their excel,I want my custom ribbon(macro buttons) to appear in their excel.However, I am failing to do so. The macros book is transferred.However,the custom ribbons/buttons i created for macros, don't transfer.Is there any standard approach to do so.

I would really appreciate if could get some source for any standard approach or reference article for sharing custom local ribbons to other PCs.

Answer (score 0):

Recommend that you simply go to the Developer tab and insert buttons on a Worksheet -- which DOES transfer from machine to machine and not worry about using the ribbon.

An additional advantage is that you have a lot more room to explain what the button does.

Comment: This would be a better answer if you described *how* to do this. Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to your question but it will simplify it for you and others you send the file to.

You can make the file install itself.
Add a workbook open and in the sub I check if the there is a file with "filename.xlam" in the add-ins folder.
If not prompt with a msgbox and ask if they want to install.

Then use copy to copy the file from it's current location to the add-ins folder (you can't move it since you have the file open).

Once the file is copied to the add-ins folder you can "install it".

```
AddIns.Add("Add-in_name").Installed = True
```

To your actual question I may have an answer.
I have done it myself but the workbook I did it on is at work and I won't be at work until Monday.
If I remember (or if you remind me) I can have a look at it how I did in my file at work.

> Edit: I just noticed this question was really old. It was at the top of my questions feed.